# Why does this recursive function looks sinusoidal?

Tags: trigonometry, partial-differential-equations, recurrence-relations

For $k,n\in \mathbb{N_+}$ and $k\leq n$, define $s(n,k)$ recursively by:
$$
\begin{align}
& s(1,1)=1\\
& \\
& s(n,1)=s(n-1,n-1)\\
& \\
& s(n,2)=\frac{n-2}{n-1}s(n-1,1)\\
& \\
& s(n,k)=\frac{n-k}{n-1}s(n-1,k-1)+\frac{k-2}{n-1}s(n-1,k-2)
\end{align}
$$

When I plot $s(n,k)$ against $k$ for fixed $n$'s, I always get a curve that looks sinusoidal:

[image]

Is there an explanation for why it should be so? I understand that a 2nd order linear recurrence relation with constant coefficients can have [periodic solutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving), but this function is apparently not such an example, since you have $s(n-1,k-1)$ and $s(n-1,k-2)$ on the right hand side instead of $s(n,\cdot)$, not to mention the changing coefficients.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom But there's $n-1$ instead of $n$ on the right hand side. If I had $n$ I can see it is 2nd-order linear recurrence relation.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Can you explain a bit more in details why? Are you suggesting it can somehow be converted into the form $a_k=c_1(k)a_{k-1}+c_2(k)a_{k-2}$?

Comment: Wolfram ran out of time $x[n,k] =  (n-k)/(n-1)*x[n-1,k-1]  +   (k-2)/(n-1)*x[n-1,k-2]$ https://www.wolframalpha.com